# Can not intersect duplicated loopcuts into model

Tags: modeling

[image]Hi,

I can't intersect the duplicated loop cuts into the model.
I first made horizontal loop cuts, then i made some vertical loop cuts and duplicated those,
it would be a quick way to repeat the cuts for putting in the windows.
The problem is that the vertical loop cuts do not intersect with the horizontal loop cuts.
I tried intersecting them, cleaning, removing doubles, joining, boolean,  etc. etc,..

Need some help here!
Using Blender 2.70a

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the face loop under the duplicated portion, then using <kbd>W</kbd>*>Bridge Edge loops* (<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! its a bit more work but clear to me now, ty  :)

Answer (score 2):

That is because you have overlapping (or not connected) geometry. If you extend the cube by extruding a face <kbd>E</kbd> instead of duplicating this wouldn't happen.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, its very clear to me now!  :)